# Hiding a Field User-Based - 50 Users Assigned to same Profile, hide ONE Filed only to ONE User

Tags: security

Hide a Field from ONE PARTICULAR USER out of 50 Users having the same Profile
I have 50 Users assigned to a Profile called Sales. I have a Custom Object called "Commission". I have a Field called **"Comission Amount" this field contains confidential data and the Management would like to HIDE this ONE Field from ONE User who is one amongst the Users with Sales Profile.** What we want to achieve is that out of 50 Users with Sales Profile, we should HIDE this ONE Field from this Object to this ONE particular user who has Sales Profile.  How to achieve this? The User can have access to Read / Write View the Object and have access to all the other Fields on this Object except for this One Field called Comission Amount.. What's the best Solution? **Note: We do not want to create a Custom Profile for this Particular User.**

Comment: You dont need to create custom profile.  In the Sales Profile, remove FLS of Commission Amount field. Create a permission set and give FLS to the permission set and assign the permission set to user who wants to see the field. I have clearly mentioned at your earlier question

Comment: I really hope you do not got with the accepted answer on your original question. It is backwards and has side effects. It is the same process as Santanu's answer just with a worse implementation

Comment: Sorry I am Lost...